# Can't find Yii2 classes in Codeception test

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2, codeception

I am beginning to use Codeception for Unit testing within Yii2. Great that Yii2 embraces it completely now, a major reason for me to upgrade!

I am having difficulties letting Codeception find the classes. Controller classes that I have written e.g. These classes load fine by autoloading in the Yii2 application.

E.g. this controller:

```
<?php

class RecipeControllerTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{
   /**
    * @var \UnitTester
    */
    protected $tester;

    protected function _before()
    {
    }

    protected function _after()
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function testMe()
    {
      echo \app\controllers\RecipesController::getallrecipes();
    }

}
```

Results when I do `codeception run unit` in the console in his output:

> FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
>
> Class '`app\controllers\RecipesController`' not found

My `_bootstrap.php` file includes this:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
```

So I am sure I'm doing something wrong but am clueless.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by explicitly creating the Yii application in the global Codeception bootstrap file.

That is, inside `tests/_bootstrap.php`, appended the following line of code:

```
new yii\web\Application(require(__DIR__ . '/../config/test.php'));
```

Most possibly it's because only in `Application` constructor the autoloaders are being actually attached to the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, what problem with namespaces.
This is example of working unit test. You can try by analogue: declare namespace and write uses at start of file.

```
<?php

namespace api\tests\unit\modules\v1\models;

use yii;
use api\tests\unit\DbTestCase;
use api\modules\v1\models\BaseModel;

class BaseModelTest extends DbTestCase {

    protected function _before()
    {
    }

    protected function _after()
    {
    }

    public function testGetSettingsValue() {
        $model = new BaseModel('project');

        $value = $model->getSettingsValue('MIN_BALANCE_FOR_OUT');
        verify($value)->equals(1000);
    }
}
```

Also, my bootstrap file have line

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/aliases.php');
```

in aliases declared aliases

```
Yii::setAlias('common', dirname(__DIR__));
Yii::setAlias('frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
Yii::setAlias('console', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/console');
Yii::setAlias('api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');
```

Answer (score 1):

When I met this error I found that I didn't have all necessary settings. This error is usually happens due to not set the app base path in the Yii2 config. Step by step:

1. Check that you have the enabled Yii2 module and the included bootstrap files in `codeception.yml`:

   ```
   paths:
       tests: tests
   <...skipped...>
   settings:
       bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
   modules:
       config:
           Yii2:
               configFile: 'config/test.php'
               cleanup: false
   ```
2. Check that you have the config file (`config/test.php`) for the tests (any other settings can be added to this minimal config):

   ```
   <?php

   return [
       'id' => 'prunto-test',
       'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
   ];
   ```
3. In `tests/_bootstrap.php` include Yii2 (`_bootstrap.php` in folders tests/unit, tests/functional and tests/acceptance can be empty):

   ```
   <?php
   define('YII_ENV', 'test');
   defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);

   require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';
   require __DIR__ .'/../vendor/autoload.php';

   // add the custom namespaces here if they are not added in the config files:
   // Yii::setAlias('frontend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend');
   // Yii::setAlias('backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
   ```
4. Check that you have the enabled Yii2 module in `tests/unit.suite` like this:

   ```
   actor: ...
   modules:
       enabled:
           - Asserts
           - Yii2
   ```
5. Rebuild codeception: `./vendor/bin/cept build`

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Solved with adding "autoload" section to the composer.json file and rebuilding composer autoload files:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "app\\": "./"
    }
}
```